# Raphael - how to select path by bounding box?

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm new to svg and raphael.js. My task is to make an interactive graph--the user clicks/touches a line and space opens to show some text elements. I have this working but the line is a very small target.

Is there a way to have the user click the bounding box instead of the path? I see getBBox() but don't see how I could use this for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is clone your path, push it back behind the line your interested in, change the attributes so that it's much thicker, and almost entirely transparent, and put your event handlers on this line.

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/enudV/)

You'll have to clean it up of course...

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a thik line of the same background color behind this line and use that as the target.

Comment: Yeah was trying to not add objects though, if there was some other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pointer-events="boundingBox"` on the element you want to capture mouseevents on. See the [SVG Tiny 1.2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty).

Here's an [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/events/pointer-events-boundingbox.svg).

Unfortunately I don't think most browsers support it yet. Opera does though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Chrome doesn't support it. Ah, web 'development' and 'applications'....